# Populate a Word Doc using Web API + Microsoft Graph

Tags: asp.net-web-api, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

We have a Word template file in OneDrive.

We have a ASP.NET Web API controller that needs to get the template, fill in the data, and save it to a new location in OneDrive.

I was surprised to see a Microsoft Graph Excel API, but not one for Word. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Word REST APIs are not available yet. Please help prioritize by adding your feature request with scenarios in Office [feedback](https://office365.uservoice.com).